# Confused with MainActivity.java in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm fairly new to java and android studio in general,and I'm trying to follow a tutorial on YouTube on how to make a simple android calculator by Andy York. I made it to part 2 of 2 until he started coding in MainActivity.java, when I noticed that ours were different and that I have stuff like "FloatingActionButton"and "SetSupportActionBar" which he doesn't have and which is confusing because if erase those then everything will mess up. I think it may have been because of an Android Studio update since his video? I'm trying to make everything neat like his but I don't know how. I hope this makes sense and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are coming because you select a that theme. So, Select the Empty Activity. Then nothing will make problem .

[image]

Comment: @J.Yates , You you find the answer helpful then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When creating new project in Android Studio use "Empty Activity" template instead of "Basic Activity". The "basic" one does add a lot of things, like a floating action button, which often isn't helpful.

[image: activity template chooser]